# Excel Index Match with IFs?? + options for next in list

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

OK I have been working on this for some time and can't quite get things right in the various combinations I have tried, so I am asking for advice.

I have a management data table where column C is a list of store numbers. Every store has a unique number but the store could be listed in Column A multiple times. Column D is my district. There are multiple districts. Column E is my job title (4 different levels). Column F is employee name.

In this set of data, every manager is listed at each store. There are several managers at each store at the same level - ie same job title.

I am looking to do the following:

**Part 1**
When Store# = (B29) in below formula, I need the the name of the person who is listed as EITHER job title GM or TRM. (I do not know which it would be GM/TM)- If neither is there return "OPEN".

I can get the formula below to give me work with either TM or GM but can't get the "IF" part to work.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Mgmt Table Data for Area 11'!$C$2:$F$3412,(MATCH(1,(B29='Mgmt Table Data for Area 11'!$C$2:$C$3412)*("GM"='Mgmt Table Data for Area 11'!$E$2:$E$3412),0)),4),"OPEN")
```

**Part 2**
How do I get it to give the next person on the list who fits the criteria for the other positions? For Example: Provide me the first name on the list who is job title RM at specific Store#y, now give me the next person in the list, and the next as I could have multiple people at the same level. I have used the SMALL/ROW function in conjunction with others in the past, but can't quite get the combination correct with Index and Match in this case.

I appreciate any help someone can provide.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to explain this better, probably with a mockup or screenshot, with an example of data and how you get to the result you want.  Particularly Part 2 is incomprehensible.